# How to delete record w/out matching record from another table?

Tags: sql-server, view

I have the following view (students w/o schyrsem) to show the list of record that don't have related record from SchYrSem table:

```
SELECT Students.IDNo, Students.LastName, Students.FirstName
FROM Students LEFT JOIN SchYrSem ON Students.[IDNo] = SchYrSem.[IDNo]
WHERE (((SchYrSem.IDNo) Is Null));
```

When I delete record it says:

view or function 'students w/o schyrsem' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Any idea how can I delete record from Students table w/o matching record in SchYrSem table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE s
  FROM dbo.Students AS s 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SchYrSem AS ss
  ON ss.IDNo = s.IDNo
  WHERE ss.IDNo IS NULL;
```

Or

```
DELETE s    
  FROM dbo.Students AS s   
  WHERE NOT EXISTS   
  (
     SELECT 1
      FROM dbo.SchYrSem
      WHERE IDNo = s.IDNo   
  );
```

You shouldn't be trying to delete a row from the view, IMHO.